# Turning proxy with password into proxy without password on localhost - for proxychains

Tags: proxy, proxychains

I am running CentOS 7 server without GUI

I have paid proxy server. This proxy server is using SOCKS5, zproxy.lum-superproxy.io:22225 and need username + password. I can not do anything on this one to make it run without password. I was trying to use it with proxychains but it it not possible because i do not have ip address but this url zproxy.lum-superproxy.io
*
So i am getting this error: proxy zproxy.lum-superproxy.io has invalid value or is not numeric*

zproxy.lum-superproxy.io have always anotehr IP address so it is not possible for me to nslookup and set ip address in number format. So in this way i am not able to use proxychains directly with my paid proxy server.

I need something like tor, so it run on localhost 127.0.0.1:9050 and no need any passwords but i need it to exit through my paid proxy server.

So i can use proxychains with it.

So what exactly i need: proxy server running on localhost, lets say on port 5555. Proxychains will connect to this 127.0.0.1:5555 and this localhsot proxy server will use my paid proxy server as exit node.

Example:

External proxy ip: 1.2.3.4 ( if i connect to proxy zproxy.lum-superproxy.io:22225 + credentials )

My server ip: 10.20.30.40

proxy server running on localhost 127.0.0.1:5555 that do not ask for credentials and that use my external proxy zproxy.lum-superproxy.io:22225 + credentials

Proxychains settings:

socks5  127.0.0.1 5555 # So now i have static number ip address that prochychains accept

So if i run proxychains wget https://showmyipaddress.com - i will see 1.2.3.4 and not 10.20.30.40

**So basically my localhost proxy server on port 5555 that do not ask for username and password just resend requests to external proxy server and use credentials to login and send data.**

ANY IDEAS HOW TO DO IT?

I tried edit tor settings to exit not over tor nodes but over my paid proxy. I tried to nslookup zproxy.lum-superproxy.io ip address to use static ip but this is not working because ip always change. Now i am out of ideas so i am here.